# Filter items in FUITableViewDataSource

Tags: swift, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI for Swift and am showing items in a TableView at the following manner:

```
let query = Database.database().reference().child("promotions").queryOrdered(byChild: "place_id").queryEqual(toValue: AccountManager.getPlaceId()!)

    dataSource = tableView.bind(to: query) { (tableView, indexPath, snap) -> UITableViewCell in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as! PromotionTableViewCell

        let title = (snap.value as? NSDictionary)?["title"] as? String

        cell.promotionNameLabel.text? = title ?? ""

        return cell
    }
```

This works just great! But now, I want to filter items based on user search in text field. Is that even possible, to filter out specific items of the list?

I'd like to have a solution for this. Anybody got a solution?

Comment: I have had issues with firebase tableview data as well!

Comment: I don't think it's possible only using Firebase with multiple filtering. Maybe, you got the main data from your Firebase database then filter your data with your own logic.